# how to use url encoded in base64 for embed in iframe using PHP

Tags: php, iframe, base64, embed

I have seen a lot of tutorials which explain how they can encode images into base64 and can be embedded but I am trying to embed a simple URL to be encoded in base64. like this below

```
<iframe src="https://somelink.com" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

I am trying to encode `https://somelink.com` into base64 which may somewhat look like this `aHR0cHM6Ly9zb21lbGluay5jb20=` can I embed this under  `iframe` in `src`  field and hide URL from being shown in view-source.

Comment: Generally, you can't hide anything on a web page. Second, an iframe's src-attribute expects a valid URL. Third, base64 is pretty recognisable, so anyone can decode it.

Comment: so iframe s src attribute value cant be encoded in base64? is there any workaround which somehow make things difficult to make url recognisable.

Comment: There is no way to do that. It wouldn't make sense either, except for pishing purposes.

Comment: are people still that dumb that they still fall for phishing trap. well my motive is to do this for securing my video links.i believe iframe height width are used to embed video links not for phishing

Comment: Sadly, they do.